# jQuery .each() function accessing other selector via indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have some code like so:

```
var theQuantities = $('#' + theWindowID + '_form INPUT[name=f\\[invoices_items\\]\\[quantity\\]\\[\\]]');
var theValues = $('#' + theWindowID + '_form INPUT[name=f\\[invoices_items\\]\\[value\\]\\[\\]]');
var theDiscounts = $('#' + theWindowID + '_form INPUT[name=f\\[invoices_items\\]\\[discount\\]\\[\\]]');
var theInvoiceTotalCell = $('#' + theWindowID + '_TDinvoice_total');
var invoiceTotal = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < theQuantities.length; i++) {
    if ($.isNumeric(theQuantities[i].val()) && $.isNumeric(theValues[i].val()) && $.isNumeric(theDiscounts[i].val())) {
        $('#' + theWindowID + '_' + theRowIDs[i].val() + '_TDinvoice_items_subtotal').html('$ ' + parseFloat((theQuantities[i].val() * theValues[i].val()) - theDiscounts[i].val()).toFixed(2));
        var theSubTotal = parseFloat((theQuantities[i].val() * theValues[i].val()) - theDiscounts[i].val()).toFixed(2);
        invoiceTotal += parseFloat(theSubTotal)
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work and I retrieve the following error `TypeError: theQuantities[i].val is not a function`

I think I need to use .each however I need to reference `theValues` and `theDisounts` as well.

What is the correct way to access other selectors with the same index within the .each() function?

Something like this that can also access the `theValues` and `theDisounts` as well:

```
theQuantities.each(function(index, item) {
    if ($.isNumeric(this.val()) && $.isNumeric(theValues[index].val()) && $.isNumeric(theDiscounts[index].val())) {
      $('#'+theWindowID+'_'+theRowIDs[index].val()+'_TDinvoice_items_subtotal').html('$ ' + parseFloat((this.val() * theValues[i].val()) - theDiscounts[i].val()).toFixed(2));
      var theSubTotal = parseFloat((this.val() * theValues[i].val()) - theDiscounts[i].val()).toFixed(2);
      invoiceTotal += parseFloat(theSubTotal);
    }
  });
```

Comment: What do you get when you log `theQuantities`?

Comment: `theValues[index]` is the same as calling [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) on `theValues` -> it returns the DOM node. Use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a jquery array object using brackets (like `theQuantities[i]`) you're getting back an HTML node element, not a jQuery object.
try using `theQuantities.eq(i)` which will return the jQuery object in position i, then you can use jQuery's `val()`

for more on eq, see jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var theSubTotal = parseFloat(($(theQuantities[i]).val() * $(theValues[i]).val()) - $(theDiscounts[i]).val()).toFixed(2);
```