# jQuery: find descendants by selector and set value by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following structure representing inputs for soccer matches:

```
<form>
    <div class="match">
        <div class="scores">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="match">
        <div class="scores">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="match">
        <div class="scores">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I want to randomly populate each input, but each pair must be different.

So this is what I tried to do:

```
$('form .match .scores').each(function () {
    var inputs = $(this).find('input[type=text]');

    // generate scores...
    inputs[0].val(score1);
    inputs[1].val(score2);
});
```

I don't know what I am missing because when trying to populate the first input the console reports the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: inputs[0].val is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `inputs[0]` returns DOM node, not jQuery set. Use `inputs[0].value = score1;` or `inputs.eq(0).val(score1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your input in a jquery selector like `$(inputs[0])` or you can use `input[0].value` since input[0] is a dom element.

```js
$(function(){

$('form .match .scores').each(function () {
    var inputs = $(this).find('input[type=text]');
    console.log(inputs);
    
    $(inputs[0]).val(score1);
    $(inputs[1]).val(score2);
});
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <div class="match">
        <div class="scores">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="match">
        <div class="scores">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="match">
        <div class="scores">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually answered a very similar question today:
[jQuery .each() function accessing other selector via indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740918/jquery-each-function-accessing-other-selector-via-indexes/39741021#39741021)

When calling a jquery array object using brackets (like `inputs[0]`) you're getting back an HTML node element, not a jQuery object.
try using `inputs.eq(0)` which will return the jQuery object in position i, then you can use jQuery's `val()`

for more on eq, see jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.